# Is it possible to add a floating point number in this BST

Tags: binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Somebody asked me this recently and I have to admit I was a little stumped and embarrassed. 
I have a tree constructed from a List of input numbers that are coming from a network say

> 3,2,4,1,5,6,7

. The tree looks like this

[image]

Question was if I have an input now coming in `3.5` where do I put it ? So where do I put it ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you would put `3.5` as the left child of the node with the value `4`, since `3.5` is larger than `3` and less than `4`.

A BST has the following properties (taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)):

1. The left subtree of a node contains only nodes with keys less than
   the node's key.
2. The right subtree of a node contains only nodes
   with keys greater than the node's key.
3. Both the left and right subtrees must also be binary search trees.
4. There must be no duplicate nodes.

Comment: Sheesh its that simple - I need to go back and study some basics of BST's